# How can I fetch value based on lowest key value in java map

Tags: java, dictionary, object, java-8

My Map is

```
Map<Long,Plan> planMap= new HashMap<>();
planMap.put(123,planObject1);
planMap.put(345,planObject2);
planMap.put(678,planObject3);
```

How do i retrive plan object based on the lowest key value
i.e : i want to retrieve planObject1 with key 123(as it is lowest).

Please help we with the possibilities

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Long minKey = Collections.min(planMap.keySet());
Plan plan = planMap.get(minKey);
```

Comment: Is there a reason for unneccessary autoboxing to `long`?

Comment: @Glains no. I'm simply more used to write the primitive.

Answer (score 2):

```
    long minPlan = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Long key : planMap.keySet()) {
        if(minPlan < key)
            minPlan= key;
    }
```

`System.out.println("min is=" + planMap.get(min));`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use another data structure or implementation, since there should be made no constraint about the order of elements  obtained from the `iterator()` of a `HashMap`. The most simple, but inefficient solution would be to iterate over the whole `entrySet()` and search for the lowest key:

```
String value = planMap.entrySet().stream()
        .min(Entry.comparingByKey()).get().getValue();
```

This does only work if the `Map` is not empty. I recommend you prefix an `isEmpty()` check.

Please note this operation has a runtime complexity of `O(n)`. If you perform this operation repeatetly, you could have a look at `TreeMap`:

```
TreeMap<Long, String> planMap = new TreeMap<>();
String value = planMap.firstEntry().getValue();
```

There is a higher cost of inserting entries into the `Map`, but retrieval can be done in `O(log n)`.

If the order *is known* at creation time of the `Map`, you can use `LinkedHashMap`, which has a defined iteration order.

```
Map<Long, String> planMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

// elements need to be added in correct order and the Map may not
// be modified after elements are inserted to not break
// consistency with the lowest key
planMap.put(123L, "Plan 1");
planMap.put(345L, "Plan 2");
planMap.put(678L, "Plan 3");

String value = planMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SortedMap<Long, Plan> planMap = new TreeMap<>();
planMap.put(123, planObject1);
planMap.put(345, planObject2);
planMap.put(678, planObject3);

Map.Entry<Long, Plan> entry = planMap.firstEntry();
```

SortedMap can be used for ranges and such.